# How to handle form show order on startup

Tags: c#, winforms

I'll try to make this question as uncomplicated as possible. I have three forms `frm_Splash` which checks for updates; `frm_Wizard` which completes first-run setup; and `frm_Main` which is the main program. These forms' relationships are diagrammed below:
[image: Form Process Chart]

Right now in `Program.cs` I have this code:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new frm_Main());
}
```

which sets `frm_Main` as my main form. What is best practice to handle `frm_Wizard` and `frm_Main`? I do not want them to load before I have finished updates (if there are any).

After this, if the wizard needs to be shown, the splash screen should disappear and the wizard should appear.

Finally, once all the updates and first-time setup is done, the main form shows (but not before). How do I accomplish all this?

**Some things I know:**

- I know I can set `frm_Splash` to be the startup form, but then when I close it, the whole program closes.
- I could also hide forms, but doesn't that waste memory with forms
  sitting in the background?

And finally, I'm looking for some general code or concepts of how to do this. I already am familiar with c# coding, so you don't need to code everything. I'm merely looking for a best practice to handle this. i.e. Should I be coding in the `Program.cs`, or each form's load event? If there's anything unclear about my question, please let me know before you downvote! Thank you.

Comment: +1 for flow charts. People who take time to write clean, well thought-out questions will get timely, well thought-out answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to note is that you do not need to use `Application.Run` to launch a form. So you can just create a 3 step process in your `Main` function:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    //Show splash form (which checks for updates)
    FormSplash splash = new FormSplash();
    splash.ShowDialog();//will wait until splash closed

    //check if first run and show if needed
    if(IsFirstRun())
    {
        FormWizard wizard = new FormWizard();
        wizard.ShowDialog();//will wait until wizard is closed
    }

    //Finally, run your application as normal
    Application.Run(new frm_Main());
}
```

NOTE: I am not aware of the benefits of using `Application.Run` to launch you main form, I assume one of them is allowing access to Application state functions (such as Exit), but I can say I have used this technique for a splash screen in the past, and have not had any issues with doing it this way

Comment: It's good for the OP to realize that he doesn't have to follow the boilerplate that MS puts in the `Main()` method

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks! I didn't know you could edit `Program.cs` in this way. Just a note though, I think you have to have `Application.EnableVisualStyles();` and `Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);` at the beginning of `Main()`. It threw me an error and that was the solution.